# Android FireBase replace key name on some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use easy code to save data to FireBase

```java
public class User_Data {
    public String id; // +
    public String lastName;

    public User_Data() {
        id = null;
        lastName = null;
    }
}

User_Data user_data = new User_Data();
user_data.lastName = "xxx";
user_data.id = "111";[![enter image description here][1]][1]
mDatabase.child("user_details").child(uid).setValue(user_data)
```

For some user was saved in Firebase correctly

[image]

But for some user was saved with replace key name with letters

[image]

**What can be the reasons?**

Comment: Intresting... have u tried to save with getter setter methods in User_Data?

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Big problem is. On my device work good every time. Strange records i can see in FireBase only

Comment: @FaisalAhmed I think, on some device java optimize property name to "a", "c"

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Comment: @FaisalAhmed Yes use. I found problem. Problem in signed .apk. In debug all ok

Comment: is everything working fine now with proguard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is

```json
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is beacause you are using User_Data object as the ID here, which is some hashed value in java environment. Change your code to this

mDatabase.child("user_details").child(uid).setValue(user_data.**id**);

Also please provide more code, issue could be something else.

Comment: I need save user_data with all fields in Firebase not user_data.id